# Solving for varible with use of ln

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Looking for some help with trying to solve for $x$ in the following equation,

$$0=5-re^{-x^2}$$

The solution is,

$$x^2=\ln\frac{r}{5}$$

Comment: Okay, and what's your question?

Comment: I am just looking for some help with the steps inbetween

Comment: This seems pretty straight forward,try to adjust the equation and take $\ln$.Also this question has nothing to do with system of equations.

Comment: We must have r>=5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\implies 5 = re^{-x^2} \iff \frac{5}{r} = e^{-x^{2}} \iff \ln\frac{5}{r} = -x^{2} \iff -\ln\frac{5}{r} = x^2 \iff \ln \frac{r}{5} = x^{2}
\end{align*}

Note: $\ln a^{n} = n\ln a$. In this case, $n=-1$, i.e. $\ln a^{-1} = -\ln a$.

Comment: does the fraction of the ln switch because of the negative sign causing the ln5 to be negative?

Comment: It's a property of logarithms. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

There you go

*0=5−re<sup>-x<sup>2</sup></sup>*

*e<sup>-x<sup>2</sup></sup>=5/r*

*ln(e<sup>-x<sup>2</sup></sup>)=ln(5/r)*

*-x<sup>2</sup>=ln(5/r)*

*x<sup>2</sup>=-ln(5/r)*

*x<sup>2</sup>=ln[(5/r)<sup>-1</sup>]*

*x<sup>2</sup>=ln(r/5)*